# Can the input with attr "x-webkit-speech" be with language other than English?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech

Currently, the Chrome x-webkit-speech seems only works well with English, can it be with other languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an attribute to `<body>` like

```
<body lang="zh-Hans">
```

No official doc for this point, just my practice.

Answer (score 8):

You can also add the `lang` attribute to your `<input>` element:

```
<input  type="text"  lang="es-MX"  x-webkit-speech  speech  onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();" />
```

This way you can have multiple controls in different languges in your page.

Cheers!

Comment: lang is a valid attribute, but the value can be just the lang code (http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/language-codes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `x-webkit-speech` attribute has been deprecated for over a year now. In favor of the JavaScript Speech recognition API. I made a JS module that impliments the API for `<input>`s:

#### [Speech input | Github](https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input)